# MFC provide a delay after drawing to the dialogwindow

Tags: c++11, mfc, delay

I have a loop, which does some drawing on the DialogWindow. And I want to add a delay in each iteration so that the user could see each line been drawn one by one.

Thought of using `Sleep`. But I believe it would make the DialogWindow non-responding.

Is there a way to add a delay at the same time allowing the events to occur?

Like in VB.net, somewhat like using `Application.DoEvents()` ? Anything in MFC C++.net ?

Comment: Maybe `SetTimer` with a period of 500ms and then draw your lines one by one in the `WM_TIMER` handler.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to add a delay at the same time allowing the events to
>   occur?
>
> Like in VB.net, somewhat like using Application.DoEvents() ? Anything
>   in MFC C++.net ?

Yes there is, CWinThread::PumpMessage(). But don't use it in this case, use the timer as suggested above.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to use a separate thread to introduce delay. There are multiple ways how you can accomplish this using thread. The other option is to use timer to do this but thread is the preferred way.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to interact with Windows resources from other than the GUI thread.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes it is generally not recommended but if you know what you are doing, drawing from thread will not break anything. What would be generally acceptable is you can have one control owned by thread to do all the drawing. If multiple threads are writing in same part, that will be not worth the trouble.

Comment: A thread is overkill for this task, I'd stick to the `SetTimer` solution as suggested before.

Comment: Multithreaded GUI rendering is not ever not a mistake. It's certainly not the preferred way.

Comment: I am surprised at the pro-timer solution for this problem. Even if you assume a simple task of drawing a 9 by 9 grid one line at a time, how would the code even look like in `WM_TIMER`handler? Maybe someone can give example? To start with you will have to tear apart the code, it will be hard to understand.

Comment: Accessing a device context from a thread other than the thread that created (and owns) the window is impossible to synchronize. Windows offers no support for this scenario at all. If you think this is incorrect, maybe you could provide sample code. A timer is the right tool. Managing state is fairly trivial.

Comment: The point I am making is from [this](http://www.amazon.com/WIN32-Multithreaded-Programming-Aaron-Cohen/dp/1565922964) book. I did some digging into it, interesting thing I noticed is that even if you are writing from a worker thread, it is still the GUI thread that is doing the actual writing in weird way (calling the GUI API from worker thread does the context switch). For this reason if the main GUI thread is blocked/waiting/sleeping, there is no worker thread that can write to GUI at that time.